# How do I run a timer as soon as user clicks one of the cells in the table view using swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, timer

I have two view controllers in my UI and what I am aiming to do is as soon as the user clicks on one of the cells in the table view, a pop up will appear (the other view controller) with a timer

However, when I build the app and click on one of the cells the label still says label and does not count down

I am also getting an error saying Unicode curly quote found replace with "" and expected digit after integer literal prefix in the same line (I indicated which line it is below)

this class is for the view controller with the table view

```
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return(redeem.count)
    }


    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {

//bringing down the array to print

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = redeem[indexPath.row]

        return(cell)
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {


        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController

        self.addChildViewController(popOverVC)
        popOverVC.view.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.addSubview(popOverVC.view)
        popOverVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)


    }
```

This class is for the PopUpViewController

```
import UIKit

class PopUpViewController: UIViewController
{

    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func closePopUp(_ sender: Any)
    {
         self.view.removeFromSuperview()
     }

     var seconds = 60
     var timer = Timer()
     var isTimeRunning = false

     override func viewDidLoad()
     {
         super.viewDidLoad()


         self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.8)


     }

     func runTimer()
     {
         timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: (#selector(PopUpViewController.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
     }

     func timeString(time:TimeInterval) -> String
     {
         let hours = Int(time) / 3600
         let minutes = Int(time) / 60 % 60
         let seconds = Int(time) % 60
//getting the error message for the line below
         return String(format:”%02i:%02i:%02i”, hours, minutes, seconds)
     }

     func updateTimer()
     {
         if seconds < 1
         {
             self.view.removeFromSuperview()
         }
         else
         {
             seconds -= 1
//getting an error message here saying EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value)
             timerLabel.text = timeString(time: TimeInterval(seconds))
         }

     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't see any call to `runTimer`. So the timer never starts. I suggest using `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`. Add this to PopupViewController:

   ```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
       super.viewWillAppear(animated)

       runTimer()
   }
   ```
2. You just call `self.view.removeFromSuperview()` to close the popup, which removes the view from view hierarchy but the viewController is still registered as child viewController. I suggest presenting the popup with `presentViewController` and removing it with `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

Present the view controller:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let popOverVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "sbPopUpID") as! PopUpViewController

        self.present(popOverVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Dismiss it with:

```
    @IBAction func closePopUp(_ sender: Any)
    {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

3. You have used the wrong quotes (” instead of "), hence the error.

Comment: Thanks, point #3 did fix the issue. Now for points #1 and #2 I am not following along very thoroughly as I would like to. I do see that now I have not called the function runTimer, how would I call it using viewDidAppear? and for point #2 how do I change that without an error?

Comment: I typed runTimer() in the viewDidLoad function and now it is crashing

Comment: Thank you, that did help me a lot. I received an additional error message on the last line of code and commented above what it said now

Comment: It seems you lost the outlet connection to timerLabel.

Comment: Don't forget to have Timer.invalidate(); Timer = nil whenever you are done with the timer.

Comment: @solenoid can you explain to be what that is and where would I put it? Thank you

Comment: When you make a timer, if you do not invalidate it properly, it will continue to run, along with any other times you call the timer. 

I usually have a method startTimer(), endTimer(), and always make sure that endTimer() is called before startTimer(). Also make sure to put stopTimer() somewhere that will get called as the view is deallocated.

I dont know that Timer = nil in swift is still necessary, but it doesnt hurt.

Comment: Ah okay that does make sense. Where would I put this code?

Answer (score 0):

Basic code needed. Remember, you need to make sure whenever you make a new timer to make sure to have invalidate() called on the existing one or you will spawn multiple timers where you probably don't want to.

```
class myClass: UIViewController {
    //...
    var timer:Timer!
    //...
    func createTimer(interval: TimeInterval, selector: Selector) {
        if timer == nil {
            timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: interval, target: self, selector: selector , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
    }
    //...
    func cancelTimer() {
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = nil
    }
    //...
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        cancelTimer()
    }
}
```